# Webpage that contains birthday dates and corresponding days for each date from birth to this year

Tags: php, html

I need help modifying this code to create a webpage that contains my birthday dates from  the day of my birth to my birthday this year and what the corresponding day of the week was for each date
[image]

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> '; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
 </head>


   <body>


      <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$year = 1997;
$ts = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year);

for($day=1; $day < 32; $day++)
{
    echo date('n/j/Y', $ts), "was a ", date('l', $ts), "<br/>";
    $ts += 24*3600;
}

?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait? What are you trying to output? Your code does not match your code or your description. Can you give a sample output?

Comment: You really want every single day in a long list like that?

Comment: Don't make your question into a moving target, it makes it impossible to answer. If your goal is to print out the day of your birthday for every year, your original code was way closer to the mark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `mktime()` command to the inside of your loop. Also, don't know why you're adding one day to your timestamp at the end of your loop, so remove that as well:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$year = 1997;

for($year; $year < 2018; $year++) {
    $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, 8, 20, $year);
    echo date('n/j/Y', $ts), " was a ", date('l', $ts), "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Andreas Huh? How does that make sense? The original code was a lot closer to what she was trying to achieve...

Comment: I know! I have no clue. Look at the image now also. Can you see why I asked for clarification? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, totally :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what Robby commented was what I was looking for.

Comment: So what did Robby comment and please edit your question to include what Robby commented to make the question clear